# Sublimetext 3 c++ compilation error "undefined reference to class::constructor()

Tags: c++, constructor, linker, sublimetext3

I have a problem with SublimeText 3 and undefined reference to class constructor. I think that the problem is with linking.

I've got main.cpp, Student.cpp and Student.h.

code is very simple for now

main.cpp:

```
    #include "Student.h"

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
      Student student1;
      return 0;
    }
```

Student.h:

```
    #ifndef _S
    #define _S 

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    class Student
    {
      public:
          Student();
          ~Student();
    };

    #endif
```

end Student.cpp

```
    #include "Student.h"

     Student::Student() {}
     Student::~Student(){}
```

Any suggestion what packages I have to install or what to change?

I would be grateful for any help

Maria

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers! I resolve the problem by making a Makefile. 
I had to install [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), that my 'make' could work, then on Sublime I've choosen BuildSystem - > Make and that how my makefile looks like:

```
    NEW=5.1
    NEW2 = Student
    KOMP=g++
    FLAGS= -std=c++11 -Wall -g

    $(NEW):$(NEW).o $(NEW2).o 
        $(KOMP) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

    $(NEW).o:$(NEW).cpp 
        $(KOMP) -c $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

    $(NEW2).o:$(NEW2).cpp $(NEW2).h
        $(KOMP) -c $(FLAGS) $^ 

    clean:
        rm -f *.o *.gch $(NEW)

    run: $(NEW)
        ./$(NEW)

    valgrind: $(NEW)
        valgrind -v ./$(NEW)

    gdb: $(NEW)
        gdb ./$(NEW)
```

after that I have to install [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) to add there variants "run" and other (remember to add , after every {} in "variants")

Hope my post could help someone too :)

Comment: Why do you want to use Sublime text for building?

Comment: Why not? It has an option to build.

Comment: Yes absolutely. what is your .buildSystem in there?

Comment: The build system in sublime for C/C++ only builds and links the single file you're editing. In theory you can modify it to not do that,but if you're going to write code you should probably learn how to use something like `make`. Sublime supports `make` directly; visit http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ and then create your own `Makefile` and it will Just Work(tm).

Comment: @OdatNurd It's not a difference if it contain gcc and I have g++?

Comment: Nope, you can swap in g++ where it's using gcc and it will work just fine. Basicaly `make` is just automating whatever steps you would take manually to build your project, plus it adds in the ability to only update/compile what has changed instead of everything every time,

Answer (score 0):

The error originated from linker because it can not see where the definition of the constructor is located. In Sublime Text 3 there is Build System "logic" like as makefile. (Tools -> Build System) 
For example a test cpp build system for Windows is somethink like that :

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"%VS120COMNTOOLS%\\..\\..\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\" amd64 && cl /nologo \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^(.*?)\\(([0-9+])(?:,([0-9+]))?\\)\\s+:\\s+(.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++"
}
```

Try to create a "build system" that fits your needs and then build your source code.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to create my own "build system" but I will try to find sth.

Comment: If you will need any help feel free to ask